# How to make validation for date in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have two dates, and I need to validate them.

This is code in my DateRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'from' => 'required|date',
        'to' => 'required|date|after:from'
    ];
}
```

'to' must be after 'from'.

But I am getting `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` error.

What I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this and use whatever rules you need. :)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'from' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|before:to',
        'to' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d|after:from',
    ];
}
```